# complex separation of variable in R

Tags: r, json, dplyr, tidyr

I have imported a large JSON file ~76000 reads using "readin" on JSONlite, this original JSON was downloaded from here:

http://mobidb.bio.unipd.it/assets/mobidb3_datasets/disorder_UP000005640.mjson.gz

I have then tried to transform it into a dataframe. Unfortunately because the content is in different formats I have ended up with 6 variable ( 5 are fine), but one contains data that looks like this:

```
list(regions = list(c("1", "101", "D"), list()), method = c("simple",
 "mobidb-lite"), dc = c(NA, 0), scores = list(NULL, c(0.875, 0.875,
 0.75, 0.625, 0.375, 0.375, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.25, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.75, 0.875, 0.875, 1, 1, 1, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.)))
```

Is there a way to separate this into columns: "List", "Method", "dc", "scores.

I have tried running extract but have not had any luck as it ran for >4 hours and didn't finish. would tidyr separate work/ what sep command would split this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the JSON file? This may be more easily corrected by changing how the JSON is parsed, than trying to fix it afterwards.

Comment: It's impossible to know for certain without seeing a sample of the original json, but know that all json cannot be converted into `data.frame` (cleanly): as soon as there is nesting (as there is now), it becomes "complicated" and impossible for the algorithm to intuit what should be done all the time.

Comment: Your code generates this:

`$regions
$regions[[1]]
[1] "1"   "101" "D"  

$regions[[2]]
list()


$method
[1] "simple"      "mobidb-lite"

$dc
[1] NA  0

$scores
$scores[[1]]
NULL

$scores[[2]]
 [1] 0.875 0.875 0.750 0.625 0.375 0.375 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125
[18] 0.125 0.125 0.250 0.250 0.375 0.500 0.750 0.875 0.875 1.000 1.000 1.000 0.875 0.875 0.875 0.000`

Not clear on how that can be converted into data frame.

Comment: the original JSON is available for download here: http://mobidb.bio.unipd.it/assets/mobidb3_datasets/disorder_UP000005640.mjson.gz    if that helps make it clearer?